# How to reformat strings to not include accented letters in Python?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make a list of locations from a column of a csv file in Python.

This is one entry in the column:

```
Rio Balira del Orien,Riu Valira d'Orient,Riu Valira d’Orient,Río Balira del Orien
```

This is the corresponding list in its current state:

```
locs = ['Rio Balira del Orien', "Riu Valira d'Orient", 'Riu Valira d\xe2\x80\x99Orient', 'R\xc3\xado Balira del Orien']
```

In my program, I need to check if a given word is in the list, so I'm trying to remove the crazy string formatting (ex. `\xc3\xad = í`) for accented letters, apostrophes, etc. and just have each location be in simple lowercase ascii. When I try to use the code

```
loclist = [x.encode('ascii').lower() for x in locs]
```

it throws the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What command should I use instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
locs = ['Rio Balira del Orien', "Riu Valira d'Orient", 'Riu Valira d\xe2\x80\x99Orient', 'R\xc3\xado Balira del Orien']
```

To remove completely:

```
print [unicode(x,errors="ignore") for x in locs]

[u'Rio Balira del Orien', u"Riu Valira d'Orient", u'Riu Valira dOrient', u'Ro Balira del Orien']
```

To encode to ascii.

```
import unicodedata
print [unicodedata.normalize('NFD', x.decode('utf-8')).encode('ascii', 'ignore') for x in locs]

['Rio Balira del Orien', "Riu Valira d'Orient", 'Riu Valira dOrient', 'Rio Balira del Orien']
```

Comment: I guess this works, if the OP is ok with losing the accented characters altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can't encode accented characters as ascii, you have to use an expanded encoding type which supports a larger character set. Right now, you have a list containing UTF-8 encoded strings, which is a reasonable way to store them. You could decode them to `unicode` objects instead, which is a good best practice:

```
>>> [l.decode('utf-8') for l in locs]
[u'Rio Balira del Orien', u"Riu Valira d'Orient", u'Riu Valira d\u2019Orient', u'R\xedo Balira del Orien']
```

You would just need to make sure you re-encoded the strings before doing things like writing them to disk, which require an encoded string. You can do that by calling `encode('utf-8')` on the `unicode` object.